# List of recursively concatenated lists in R

Tags: r, list, recursion

Is there a *concise* way to create a list of recursively concatenated lists in R?

Here’s a concrete illustration of the type of problem I’d like to solve: Given two lists, such as

```
u <- list("A", list("B", list("C", "D")), "E")
v <- c("x", "y")
```

I would like to (recursively) produce the following list of character vectors

```
w <- list(c("A", "x"), c("A", "y"),
          c("B", "C", "x"), c("B", "C", "y"),
          c("B", "D", "x"), c("B", "D", "y"),
          c("E", "x"), c("E", "y"))
```

By “concise” I mean in an R-idiomatic manner with a minimal number of explicit for-loops.

**What I’ve tried**: I first tried solving the more basic problem of pairwise concatenation, that is, the problem of forming a list like

```
r <- list(c("A", "x"), c("A", "y"), c("B", "x"), c("B", "y"),
          c("C", "x"), c("C", "y"))
```

from two lists like

```
p <- list("A", "B", "C")
q <- list("x", "y")
```

However, performing the seemingly sensible operation

```
outer(p, q, FUN = "c")
```

threw the exception

```
dims [product 6] do not match the length of object [12]
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be

```
 w1 <- do.call(c,lapply(u, function(x) {
        x1 <- if(!is.list(x)) outer(x,v, FUN=paste) 
        else t(outer(do.call(paste, x), v, FUN= paste))
        strsplit(x1, " ")}))
identical(w, w1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That works, thanks! It would be neater, however, if the solution could apply to lists nested to arbitrary depth. (But I suppose that is just a matter of applying the `outer` part, recursively … )